# Cannot fetch data from the backend [ JWT Laravel React ]

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, jwt

I am using Reactjs, Laravel and JWT. I am trying to login and fetch data from the backend into dashboard after I log in but it gives me "Request failed with status code 500". I have tried with get instead of post but doesnt work. If I removed "http.post" stuff in dashboard.js it doesnt give error but I need it as I need user's details.

Laravel
api.php

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class,'register']);

Route::group(['middleware'=>'api'],function(){
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class,'logout']);
    Route::post('refresh', [AuthController::class,'refresh']);
    Route::post('me', [AuthController::class,'me']);
});
```

Reactjs :
Auth.js

```
export default function AuthUser(){

const navigate = useNavigate();

const getToken = () =>{
    const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken;
}

const getUser = () =>{
    const userString = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    const user_detail = JSON.parse(userString);
    return user_detail;
}



const [token,setToken] = useState(getToken());
const [user,setUser] = useState(getUser());

const saveToken = (user,token) =>{
    sessionStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(token));
    sessionStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));

    setToken(token);
    setUser(user);
    navigate('/dashboard');
}

const logout = () => {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    navigate('/login');
}

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:8000/api",
    headers:{
        "Content-type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
    }
});
return {
    setToken:saveToken,
    token,
    user,
    getToken,
    http,
    logout
}
}
```

Dashboard.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AuthUser from './AuthUser';

export default function Dashboard() {

const {http} = AuthUser();
const [userdetail,setUserdetail] = useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
    fetchUserDetail();
},[]);

const fetchUserDetail = () =>{
    http.post('/me').then((res)=>{
        setUserdetail(res.data);
    });
}

function renderElement(){
    if(userdetail){
        return <div>
            <h4>Name</h4>
            <p>{userdetail.name}</p>
            <h4>Email</h4>
            <p>{userdetail.email}</p>
        </div>
    }else{
        return <p>Loading.....</p>
    }

}

return(
    <div>
        <h1 className='mb-4 mt-4'>Dashboard page</h1>
        { renderElement() }
    </div>
)
}
```

I am trying to follow https://github.com/AjayYadavAi/react-js-authentication-laravel tutorial but it works on his and not mine. I did the exact same thing.

laravel.logs:

```
/Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php(44): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Hmac->doVerify('\\xAB\\xE5d\\xA5\\x10X\\x10\\xD5\\x17\\x9C\\x80\\xAC\\xD2\\xDD\\xBF...', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', NULL)
#1 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signature.php(49): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\BaseSigner->verify('\\xAB\\xE5d\\xA5\\x10X\\x10\\xD5\\x17\\x9C\\x80\\xAC\\xD2\\xDD\\xBF...', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', NULL)
#2 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Token.php(202): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signature->verify(Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Hmac\\Sha256), 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', NULL)
#3 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/Providers/JWT/Lcobucci.php(136): Lcobucci\\JWT\\Token->verify(Object(Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Hmac\\Sha256), NULL)
#4 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/Manager.php(101): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Providers\\JWT\\Lcobucci->decode('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...')
#5 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php(200): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Manager->decode(Object(Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Token))
#6 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php(136): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWT->getPayload()
#7 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php(149): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWT->checkOrFail()
#8 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/tomfordrumm/jwt-auth/src/JWTGuard.php(79): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWT->check(true)
#9 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.php(60): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWTGuard->user()
#10 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(63): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\JWTGuard->check()
#11 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(42): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->authenticate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Array)
#12 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#13 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(723): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(698): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#17 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(651): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#36 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /Users/myname/smproject/backend/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/myname...')
#39 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Is there any information in the body of the response? Or some logs on the server? Not sure why you showed all that front end code since it's clearly a server error

Comment: @JaromandaX I added log from laravel.log. Could you have a look please ? Thanks

Comment: did "php artisan jwt:secret" again and it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry to here that.